# Regex capturing group only capturing last occurence

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

Here is my input:

```
start

        @var=somevar1
        @var=somevar2

end
```

I am using this regex

```
start(?:\s*\n*(?:@var=(.*)\s*)*)\s*\n*end
```

Its should give the output as

```
somevar1
somevar2
```

but its giving just somevar2.

Is there any way to get all occurrence of the capturing group?

Comment: You can use 2 phase approach so first get text between `start` and `end` then get match your `@` strings.

Comment: You might also use an infinite quantifier in the lookbehind, which ishttps://regex101.com/r/9uzpYD/1 getting more supported `(?<=^start\s[^]*@var=)\S+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a positive lookbehind with an inifite quantifier to assert start followed by a newline at the left.

See the [support for lookbehinds](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind).

```
(?<=^start\n[^]*@var=)\S+(?=[^]*\nend$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ESAI8D/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=^start\n[^]*@var=)\S+(?=[^]*\nend$)/gm;
const str = `start

        @var=somevar1
        @var=somevar2

end`;
let m;

console.log(str.match(regex));
```

If there can only be formats of @var=somevar preceding and following instead of other content:

```
(?<=^start\n\s*(?:@var=\S+\s+)*@var=)\S+(?=(?:\s*@var=\S+)*\s*\nend$)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ebHkSU/1)